# Is it possible to limit RunningValue to look back for a certain number of rows?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Im trying to average the past 5 rows in my table i created in SSRS grouped by date(Monday of every week). Ive tried runningValue however it looks back at all the past rows for each group. Is there a way to limit the scope to just the past 5 rows or weeks for each Date group.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know there is no simple way to do this in SSRS. I would suggest doing this in your dataset query using windowed functions but I think they were only introduced into SQL Server after 2008 (which I'm guess is your database version?).

The other option is to use some VB code in your report, see this post that discusses a very similar problem.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a9320181-9c25-45f6-9ee5-7466bbfe8d38/ssrs-2008-r2-add-moving-average-to-column-group?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would accomplish this with grouping. I don't know what your dataset is like but I assume it is a SQL query you can modify. The easiest solution would be to add a week number column to your query. For example:

```
SELECT datepart(week, YOURDATE) as WeekNumber
```

More info on datepart:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Once you have a week number, use the table creation wizard in Report Builder and add WeekNumber as a row group. This will group your values by week number and give you a total under each week. You can change the total by double clicking and making it AVG() instead of SUM().

Note: If you already have each 5 day period in a group, you should be able to right click that and add total. At which point you can just change the SUM to AVG there.